# Node decryption for AES-CCM decryption from object

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, aes

I have been given an object with following structure:

```
const encrypted_key = {
    'iv': 'LmckiIdRw==',
    'v': 1,
    'iter': 10000,
    'ks': 256,
    'ts': 64,
    'mode': 'ccm',
    'adata': '',
    'cipher': 'aes',
    'salt': 'UG5/bQ=',
    'ct': 'F8zKwLKMKoQ='
}
```

I have looked at every library on npm, but none of them take in all the properties shown here.

I would appreciate any guidance on a JS function or library on how to decrypt this AES-CCM object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the output of the demo page of SJCL, see [here](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/demo/). It is a combination of the properties for PBKDF2 password derivation (which takes the `iter`, `ks` and `salt`.

The rest is for the CCM mode decryption, except for `v` which simply indicates version 1. The CCM mode decryption of course also requires the key which is derived from a user supplied password by PBKDF2 using the parameters mentioned before.

The binary data is base 64 encoded.